# NetFlow v5 - exporting flow records missing fields

Tags: c++, pcap, libpcap, netflow

I am implementing my own NetFlow v5 offline exporter and I am struggling with a couple of fields there:

1. 8-11 nexthop IP address of next hop router
2. 12-13 input SNMP index of input interface
3. 14-15 output SNMP index of output interface - no idea what these are
4. 20-23 dOctets Total number of Layer 3 bytes in the packets of the flow - don't know how to count it or where to get it
5. 39 tos IP type of service (ToS) - same here

I have no idea after several hours of browsing the Internet where to get these items. I would really appreciate if you anyone can point me some direction. Thanks!

Comment: Which platform do you implement NetFlow? I'm looking for NetFlow open-source for embedded Linux but found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Petr:  this answer may come a little too late for you, but here's some thoughts that should help.  The NetFlow protocol was originally developed by CISCO to be used on routers and switches.

Therefore, things like the 'nexthop' IP address is the IP of the next forwarding device based on the routing table in the router.  You can simply set it to the same address as the destination IP.

Similarly, the SNMP ifIndex is the interface number where the flow is respectively flowing into, and out of.  Real ifIndex numbers cannot be 0, so set them to something imaginative.

dOctents is fairly important.  It is the number of bytes in the flow, counting IP and protocol packet headers also.  Basically, the sum of how big all the packets in the flow are.

The ToS field is the QoS field in IPv4, or the DiffServ field from IPv6.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the hints, although I finished (very successfully) the project in December. If you want to see it I placed it on my github: https://github.com/petrstehlik/School/tree/master/ISA